# Identifier has already been declared using .html(data)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Every time that I click in a button of the sidebar, this function runs:

```
function loadContent(event, tabName){
    $("#pane").empty()
    if(event !== undefined && tabName !== undefined){
        oldTabname = tabName
        $("#pane").load(tabName)
    }
    else{
        $.get(oldTabname).done(function(data){
            $("#pane").html(data)
        })
    }
}
```

but when the tab load, if this tab contains any require inside of the js file equals the last tab it gave the error: SyntaxError: Identifier has already been declared.

There is any way to clear the div pane?

Comment: Typo.  You have mis-matched curly braces and parentheses.  Basically, you never closed the first call to `.done()`.

Comment: Right, I updated the .done() but still giving this error

Comment: Your question is not clear. I understand that there are buttons in a sidebar, and when a button is clicked the `#pane` div is emptied and reloaded with content from a file (name stored in the variable `tabName`). However, I do not understand the problem. This sentence is not clear: *`if this tab contains any require inside of the js file`* - what does that mean? Please be very specific. It would also help if you show us the inside of one of your `tabName` files - we need to identify ***what*** `Identifier` was already declared. Click `edit` below your question and make it more clear.